Firebase Messaging component is not present in react native
Notification permission denied

[Error: Exception in HostObject::get(propName:RNFBMessagingModule):
java.lang.NullPointerException: Firebase Messaging component is not
present]

I used different methods but still issues is there. In code we used this package

@react-native-firebase/messaging 



Can you share your package.json file?
Also make sure you follow these steps -

This module @react-native-firebase/app is already setup and installed in your app.
Also make sure you follow this step while installing firebase in your app like in this documentation -> https://rnfirebase.io/


please considering going through following check points.

Configure Firebase with Android credentials
To allow Firebase on Android to use the credentials, the
google-services plugin must be enabled on the project. This requires
modification to two files in the Android directory.
First, add the google-services plugin as a dependency inside of your
/android/build.gradle file:

buildscript {
  dependencies {
    // ... other dependencies
    // NOTE: if you are on react-native 0.71 or below, you must not update
    //       the google-services plugin past version 4.3.15 as it requires gradle >= 7.3.0
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1'
    // Add me --- /\
  }
}


Generating iOS credentials
On the Firebase console, add a new iOS application and enter your
projects details. The "iOS bundle ID" must match your local project
bundle ID. The bundle ID can be found within the "General" tab when
opening the project with Xcode.

if all of above checks out then look for the core cause

Android - Requesting permissions
On Android API level 32 and below, you do not need to request user
permission. This method can still be called on Android devices;
however, and will always resolve successfully. For API level 33+ you
will need to request the permission manually using either the built-in
react-native PermissionsAndroid APIs or a related module such as
react-native-permissions

  import {PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native';
  PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.POST_NOTIFICATIONS);


iOS - Requesting permissions
iOS prevents messages containing notification (or 'alert') payloads
from being displayed unless you have received explicit permission from
the user.

import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

async function requestUserPermission() {
  const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
  const enabled =
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

  if (enabled) {
    console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus);
  }
}


The permissions API for iOS provides much more fine-grain control over
permissions and how they're handled within your application. To learn
more, view the advanced iOS Permissions documentation.


I tried this solution also.

Resolved with below solution :

 <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingRegistrar" android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />

 <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsRegistrar" android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
 </service>


While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

please add bit of explanation and then accept it as answer so it will be marked as solved for the system.
